# Signals and binding arguments

Tags: c++, boost, signals, bind

I'm using `boost::signals2` library and here is the simple code:

```
boost::signals2<void ()> sig;
class Foo {
   void Slot() {}
};

Foo obj;
sig.connect( boost.bind(&Foo::Slot, &obj) );
```

Everything works well. But now I want my signal to pass some data in arguments:

```
boost::signals2<void (std::vector<float>)> sig2;
class Foo {
   void Slot2(std::vector<float>) {}
};
```

What is the right way to bind Slot2 to signal again?

Here is the error: http://dpaste.com/752076/ when I use same connect&binding code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a placeholder:

```
sig.connect( boost::bind(&Foo::Slot, &obj, _1) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to read [Automatic Connection Management](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#signals2.tutorial.connection-management), where a similar example exists on how to connect a slot that takes arguments.

In your case, it is like this :

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
   void Slot1() {}
   void Slot2(std::vector<float>) {}
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void ()> st1;
    typedef st1::slot_type sst1;
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void (std::vector<float>)> st2;
    typedef st2::slot_type sst2;

    st1 sig1;
    st2 sig2;

    Foo foo;

    sig1.connect( sst1( &Foo::Slot1, foo ) );
    sig2.connect( sst2( &Foo::Slot2, foo, _1 ) );

    sig1();
    std::vector<float> v(5,2.2);
    sig2( v );
}
```